# i cant extract data into variables from my database

Tags: mysql, select

## I cant extract data into variables from my database.

It works fine on my localhost wit xampp.
I want to echo the vaiables in a html table

the code is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products" ;
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('The query could not be completed');

while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  print_r($result) ;

  $name=$row['Name'] ;
  $text=$row['Text1'] ;
  $year=$row['Year'] ;
  $origin=$row['Origin'] ; 
  $img=$row['Image'] ; 
  $id=$row['IDproduct'] ;
```

the print_r is to test and it just gives me:

```
     mysqli_result Object
  (
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 6
    [lengths] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 15
            [3] => 205
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 13
        )

    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)
```

where the [0] to [5] should be the column names and the values are actually some text

on other pages i use Insert and Delete queries that work just fine for storing data into the database

Comment: What does `print_r($row)` look like? What values are you getting in those variables?  How are you checking what values are in those variables?

Comment: thanks @JNevil that helped me solve the problem, i should have checked the variables differently